# Can you provide a unique ID on the row (TR) if you load data through a URL?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use this plugin: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

I load the data through a URL and it returns the following JSON format:

```
{
   "total":1,
   "rows":[
      {
         "id_account":"1",
         "email":"cool@magikweb.ca",
         "first_name":"Vincent",
         "last_name":"Morino",
         "type":"R\u00e9gulier ou personnalis\u00e9",
         "status":"Actif",
         "billing":"Non",
         "name":"Vincent Morino"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there any way I can return the `id_account` in a way so it's applied to the `<tr>`?

I apply `data-url="base-data.php?identifier=listing-users"` on the HTML table and initialize it like this:

```
$('.table').bootstrapTable({
    pagination: true,
    sidePagination: "server",
    showColumns: true
});
```

The HTML context:

```
<table id="listing-users" class="table table-striped table-hover" data-url="base-data.php?identifier=listing-users">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Nom du contact</th>
            <th data-field="email" data-sortable="true">Adresse électronique</th>
            <th data-field="type" data-sortable="true">Droits d'accès</th>
            <th data-field="billing" data-sortable="true">Utilisateur à facturer?</th>
            <th data-field="status" data-sortable="true">État</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

In other words, I want to put anything that identifies the row so when it's selected, I can have a unique identifier to play with.

My first attempt was to add `data-field="id_account"` on the TR element in the previously stated HTML context, but no success.

Comment: try `data-id-field`... but that may only apply to the table. Not sure...

Comment: I just tried it and here is the result: `data-id-field` remains on the `<thead>'s <tr>` and is not interpreted, it litterally shows `data-id-field="id_account"`. The children `<tr>`s do not have anything excepted the usual `data-index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/658
I've found that the option `data-unique-id` works and applies a markup directly onto the TR.

Answer (score 0):

`data-id-field` goes on the tables tag like this :

```
<table id="listing-users" class="table table-striped table-hover" data-url="base-data.php?identifier=listing-users" data-id-field="id_account">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Nom du contact</th>
        <th data-field="email" data-sortable="true">Adresse électronique</th>
        <th data-field="type" data-sortable="true">Droits d'accès</th>
        <th data-field="billing" data-sortable="true">Utilisateur à facturer?</th>
        <th data-field="status" data-sortable="true">État</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

or you can simply specify it in the jQuery initialization :

```
$('.table').bootstrapTable({
   pagination: true,
   sidePagination: "server",
   showColumns: true,
   idField: 'id_account'
});
```

UPDATE `2015-04-15`:

Just a little update, to tell you that finally I didn't had the `data-id-field` either on my TR. I was using both `idField` and `uniqueId`, `uniqueId` was writing is value in the TR, not `idField`.

But my function was working for me, because I used only `idField` to update my row at the time of this post (and it seems like only the `updateRow` function is working with it) as when I try to hide the row with it, it doesn't work.

So, if you want to follow up the issue as it will get resolved, you can, here : https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/583

Comment: Do you currently use the version `1.7.0` ?

Comment: Yes! I just updated it before replying to your comment.

Comment: What if you try with the js variable instead ?

Comment: Same result, no markup at all anywhere excepted for the `data-index`. I actually need the markup, but could it be that the ID is stored in a JS array in memory?

Comment: I can't tell, sorry this code works here for me .. but i'm only playing with data on the client side for now, try that to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try it out with local data, I'd assume that the AJAX call doesn't apply the corresponding ID internally.